# Unpacking zip file in c# using System.IO.Packaging

Tags: c#, zip, system.io.packaging

I want to unzip a file in c# using the System.IO.Packaging namespace. I know there is a zip library, but I would rather first explore if I can achieve the same without adding extra dependencies.

Here is my code:

```
using (var fs = new FileStream(fn1, FileMode.Open)) {
    using (var p = Package.Open(fs)) {
        Console.WriteLine(p.GetRelationships().Count());
        Console.WriteLine(p.GetParts().Count());
    }
}
Console.Read();
```

Using any zip file I find, I get 0 relationships and 0 parts. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `ZipPackage` is indeed not capable of handling arbitrary zip-archives. And I believe that's the reason why the class is called `ZipPackage` rather than `ZipArchive`. Probably we will have a proper `ZipArchive` implementation in some future version of the framework as BCL Team actually [worked on the API](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2010/06/28/working-with-zip-files-in-net.aspx) some time ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, though all System.IO.Packaging files are zip files, not all zip files conform to System.IO.Packaging. As such, it is useless for unpacking zip files.

Comment: I wouldn't go that far. It's usefulness is just limited.